# Handling Crystal Reports without parameters

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

I currently run a Windows service that exports Crystal Reports to PDF on schedule. Out of the 66 reports that run, 5 or so have no parameters defined.

Using the Crystal Reports DLL, I understand that the ReportDocument.Export() method requires parameters, as I have been experiencing the "missing parameter values" exception when it hits the ReportDocument.Export() method.

I'm currently doing my set parameters in this method:

```
private void SetParameters(string rawParameters = null)
        {
            var crystalParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var parameters = String.IsNullOrEmpty(rawParameters) ? null : HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(rawParameters);

            if(parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (string rawKey in parameters.AllKeys)
                {
                    var value = parameters[rawKey];
                    // Check for array value (e.g. key[0]=value)
                    var arrayCheck = Regex.Match(rawKey, @"^(.+)\[[0-9]?\]$");
                    if (arrayCheck.Success)
                    {
                        var key = arrayCheck.Groups[1].Value;
                        // Existing entry for this key, reconstruct object array with this added
                        if (crystalParameters.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            var newParameterArray = new object[((object[])crystalParameters[key]).Count() + 1];
                            int i = 0;
                            foreach (object item in (object[])crystalParameters[key])
                            {
                                newParameterArray[i++] = item;
                            }
                            newParameterArray[i++] = (object)value;
                            crystalParameters[key] = (object)newParameterArray;
                        }
                        // New array value
                        else
                            crystalParameters[key] = (object)new object[] { value };
                    }
                    // Discrete value
                    else
                        crystalParameters[rawKey] = (object)parameters[rawKey];
                }

                foreach (string parameter in crystalParameters.Keys)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.reportDocument.SetParameterValue(parameter, crystalParameters[parameter]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Ignore invalid parameter exceptions, otherwise throw again
                        if (ex.HResult != -2147352565)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested a couple of scenarios, including `ReportDocument.SetParameterValue("", "")`. However, I resolved the issue when and only when I blanked out this if clause; reserving this method to be called only when the report does have parameters.